# How can i extract string using regex?

Tags: php, regex

`$str = (( test:   'object1',   test2:  'object2',    test3:   'object3' ))`

Out of the above string, I want to extract the word `object1`.

So, I wrote following code, but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
  echo preg_replace("/^(.+)test:(.+)'(.+)'(.+)$/", "$3", $str);
?>
```

It printed "object3"

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `/^(.+?)test:(.+?)'(.+)'(.+)$/`

Comment: @AvinashRaj It return ** object1',   test2: 'object2',    test3: 'object3 ** . :(

Comment: did you replace the matched code with `$3` ?

Comment: @YouHoGeon, you want to replace `object1` word with something or to get the value of `test` key?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this regex:

```
.*?test:\s*'(.+?)'.*
```

Your example:

```
$str = "(( test:   'object1',   test2:  'object2',    test3:   'object3' ))";
echo preg_replace("/.*?test:\s*'(.+?)'.*/", "$1", $str); //: object1
```

Comment: So the $1 fetch the first object1, if i write it $2 then second object2. Is it like  that or how is it.

Comment: No, this regex only works for the key `test:`. If you want to catch `'object2'`, you'll replace the regex by this one: `.*?test2:\s*'(.+?)'.*`